# knexjs and postgres: whereRaw within a join

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, join, knex.js

In the following code I am joining two table and searching for a proper name:

```
const homesWithUsers = knex('homes')
  .join('users', 'homes.id', 'users.home_id')
  .whereRaw(
     `LOWER("homes.name") LIKE ?`,
     '%' + payload.home_name.toLowerCase() + '%'
   )

//Stringified
select * from "homes" inner join "users" on "homes"."id" = "users"."home_id" where LOWER("homes.name") LIKE '%george%'
```

I need to use `whereRaw` because the database column and the search term are proper names where capitalization is uncertain. (Storing an extra column of the proper names represented in all uppercase is not an option.) However, this query fails with: `error: column "homes.name" does not exist`. If I remove `homes.` the query is ambiguous (`error: column reference "name" is ambiguous`) because both the `user` and `home` tables have the columns `name`.

If I do a simple `where` statement the query is successful

```
  const homesWithUsers = knex('funeral_homes')
    .join('users', 'homes.id', 'users.home_id')
    .where({ 'homes.name': payload.home_name })
    .select('*');
```

The only problem is that this will fail with the payload values I expect to field from users interacting with the database.

Any suggestions for how to successfully perform a `whereRaw` on a joined table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use identifier replacement syntax `??` when passing column identifiers to raw, which needs to be quotet properly. Like this:

```
const homesWithUsers = knex('homes')
  .join('users', 'homes.id', 'users.home_id')
  .whereRaw(
     `LOWER(??) LIKE ?`, ["homes.name", '%' + payload.home_name.toLowerCase() + '%']
   )
```